# get from one div all child divs id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I get all div IDs in children of "test" div?

The selector below gives only "dog": i need get "dog", "cat", "drig", for example.

```
var all = $(".test div").attr("id");
$("div").text(all);

<div class="test">
    <div id="dog"></div>
    <div id="cat"></div>
    <div id="drig"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean all the direct descendants of the element, than you have to change your selector to  `$(".test > div")` (it's the [*child selector*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)). If you want to select *all* descendants, then you can leave it as it is.

Using [**`.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/map/), you can create an array of IDs:

```
var all = $(".test > div").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) here

```
var idArray = $("div.test > div").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yJNS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test div").each( function() {

   console.log( $(this).attr("id") );

});
```

[example in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/usase/edit#preview)

Answer (score 0):

if you need all divs in .test

`$('div.test div)`

but if you have

```
<div class="test">
    <div id="dog"></div>
    <div id="cat"></div>
    <div id="drig">
            <div id="mouse"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you don't need #mouse

`$('div.test > div')`

Comment: This explains how to select the right elements, but not how to get the IDs.